# Не понимаю как использовать свой пулл данных с @DataProvider, TestNG

Tags: java, testng

У меня есть  `ArrayList<String> A`, который имеет элементы (1,2,3...10).
Теперь мне нужно использовать данные с 1 по 5 и с 6 по 10. Т.е. в функции, что получает данные имеем следующее:

```
@Test (dataProvider="1")
public void insrt(String el1,String el2,String el3,String el4,String el5) {
        //работа с данными
    }


а сам датапровайдер выглядит вот так
```

```
@DataProvider (name = "1")
    public Object[][] dateIn( ArrayList<String> A){
        return new Object[][] {{A.get(0),A.get(1),A.get(2),A.get(3),A.get(4)
        }};
    }
```

Но у меня в выводе только ошибки . Вопрос: как мне использовать нужное кол-во данных из нужного мне источника данных в DataProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
class MyTest {

  ArrayList<String> A = asList(1, 2, 3, ..., 10);

  @Test (dataProvider="1")
  public void insrt(String el1,String el2,String el3,String el4,String el5) {
    //работа с данными
  }

  @DataProvider (name = "1")
  public Object[][] dateIn(){
    return new Object[][] {
        {A.get(0),A.get(1),A.get(2),A.get(3),A.get(4)},
        {A.get(5),A.get(6),A.get(7),A.get(8),A.get(9)}
    };
  }
```

}

Или так

```
    class MyTest {

      ArrayList<String> A = asList(1, 2, 3, ..., 10);

      @Test (dataProvider="1")
      public void insrt(List<String> elements) {
        //работа с данными
      }

      @DataProvider (name = "1")
      public Object[][] dateIn(){
        return new Object[][] {
            {A.subList(0, 5)},
            {A.subList(5, 10)}
        };
      }
}
```